# Why the listview inside the fragment is not working?

Tags: android, list, listview, fragment

I'm trying to put a list view inside a fragment. I made tries and here is what I got (My app is working, but the list view simply doesn't appear.):

The Fragment I want the list in:

```
public class Trechos extends Fragment {

    ListView list;


    @Override
    //Método para inflar o layout
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle
            savedInstanceState){


        //Variável view to tipo View infla o layout a ser usado
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trechos, container, false);

        Classe classe = new Classe(getActivity());

        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

        list.setAdapter(classe);

        //retorna a variável view
        return view;

    }

}
```

The xml for the fragment:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

  </ListView>

  <ListView
      android:id="@id/android:empty"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:text="adasdasds">

  </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The custom adapter I created to insert the informations:

```
public class Classe extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private String [] trechos = {"a", "b"};
    private int [] posicao = {1,2};


    public Classe(Activity context) {

        super(context, R.layout.row_layout);

        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null, true);

        TextView txtPosicao = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.posicao);

        TextView txtTrecho = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.trechos);

        txtPosicao.setText(posicao[position]);

        txtTrecho.setText(trechos[position]);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And the xml for the custom rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/posicao"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />


        <TextView
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/trechos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you have two listviews? Isn't the latter obscurring the view of the first? Also how can you set android:text on a ListView?

Comment: Because I will populate the list from a server, the second list view appears when there's no connection to the internet. The id is different as you can see.

Comment: Have you tried setting the visibility of the second list view to gone/invisible? It may be covering up the list view you're trying to populate

Comment: I exclude the other list view, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Youre trying to use empty views? If that is the case, try extending `ListFragment`. And there exists an `@id/android:list`, by the way

Comment: Is your app not crashing? `txtPosicao.setText(posicao[position]);` shouldn't work... It needs to be `txtPosicao.setText(""+posicao[position]);`. If your app isn't crashing, then you haven't loaded that Fragment, so please do [edit] your question to include the FragmentTransaction code of the Activity

Comment: But if I extend to list fragment it gives me an error on the FragmentPagerAdapter, which returns the fragment that I'm using.

Comment: No, it's not crashing, it just don't show the list I created. Don't get why it should crash?

Comment: The error probably says you are required to use a layout that needs the id I mentioned in the previous comment

Comment: `setText(int resourceId)` will throw a ResourceNotFoundException

Comment: @OP Is there any CONCRETE error or exception happening? Two listviews with match_parent seem shady but if you give us more info we may be able to help better. Check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: also you might want to override the getCount() method since it's returning 0 right now. That's maybe why the getView() method is not being called ultimately resulting in not seeing anything appear in the ListView.

Comment: No, the getCount is returning the number of tabs